# Drumming on tables on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, music

We know there is an Isur to play instruments on Shabbat (S"A 338 IIRC), to clap or dance. 
A few questions:

1) Is it is permissible to drum on tables with one's hands?

2) What about with forks or the like?

The Sefer Shabbat KaHalacha brings two opinons:

> אין לתופף על שולחנות וסכו"ם משום שנחשב ככלי נגינה ויש נוהגים להקל בזה .

I remember seeing both ways for the practice of drumming with hands but I think with forks it's universal to prohibit.

Please CYLOR

Comment: At most you can say it's a machloket about clapping. The mishna forbids it, but it is permitted by many authorities now.

Comment: @Daniel I'd usually call that sort of situation _Ta'ah beDevar Mishna_ not a Machloket. IAE who said this case is analogous to clapping?

Answer (score 2):

In the next siman 339:3 the Mechaber himself writes that clapping on a לוח (board) with rhythm is forbidden because of the gezairah of tikkin kli. The Rema notes that there are those who permit (I believe that is Tosfos shittah in the gemarah).

It seems from the Mechaber any rhythmic tune is forbidden to do; even to knock on a door using a tune would be forbidden by many.

Comment: Not clear that the quoted heter applies to the tapping case. See Mishna Berura.

Comment: The Mishnah Brurah meant playing actual instruments

Comment: I could be wrong,but the Rema holds that shittah.

Comment: The MB says "the other things in this Seif". Playing actual musial instruments is not in that Seif.

Comment: Does he? What happened to סתם וי"א הלכה כסתם?

Comment: I am not sure about Rama,but the Mechaber is clear