# What is rationale behind banging on table during bentching?

Tags: minhag, bentching

There is one family that I occasionally eat with that has a minhag of banging on the table during Birkat ha-Mazon. I was wondering what reasons lay behind this custom.

I do not know if this is relevant, but there is a particular rhythm that they have (the following description only would apply on Shabbat):

Bang #1  Middle of Psalm 126 right after "הגדיל יי לעשות עם אלה" (Hashem has done great things for them)

Bang #2  Near the end of Psalm 126 before "בא יבא ברנה"

Remaining bangs:  Every off-beat during final paragraph of abridged version (Oseh shalom bi-m'romav etc.)

I do not think it is just a custom they made up themselves, since one time at the local Orthodox shul I saw an (unrelated) guy do the two bangs on the introductory psalm, but not at the end (presumably since we said the full version?).  I noticed it because usually at the shul nobody does any banging at all.  Any information you have for an origin or reason would be interesting.

This post [Drumming on tables on Shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30695/drumming-on-tables-on-shabbat) is kind of relevant as to whether this is permissible, but that is not really my question.

Comment: we used to bang on the table for "al shulchan zeh" and then I saw kids from camp engage in a rhythmic banging and series of hand motions for the final paragraph. I assumed the latter was just a camp thing.

Comment: I've been told it was (and is) a camp thing.

Answer (score 3):

I really would not call it a minhag,it is more to make bentching more entertaining for the children(and even sometimes the adults).This has been practiced almost in every yeshivish day camp and sleep away camp that I know of.